# Python - How to get all possible combinations from nested list

Tags: python

I have a nested list like this :

```
values = [['DNO', 0.2], ['Equinor', 0.4], ['Petoro', 0.2], ['Total', 0.2]]
```

How to get all possible combinations of elements that will have a sum(2nd element of each sub list) greater than 0.5?

This is what I am using :

```
def getCombinations(values, min_len):
    combo = "\n"
    numbers = []
    doc = {}
    for val in values:
        doc[val[0]] = val[1]
        numbers.append(val[1])

    result = [seq for i in range(len(numbers), 0, -1) for seq in itertools.combinations(numbers, i) if sum(seq) >= 0.5]
    temp = doc.copy()

    for r in result:
        doc = temp.copy()
        if len(r) >= min_len:
            for rr in r:
                combo = combo + get_key(doc, rr) + " "

                doc.pop(get_key(doc, rr))
            combo = combo + "\n"
    return combo
```

My algorithm have some problem when there are multiple values like 0.2 in above list.

Currently it is returning this with `min_length=3`:

```
Total Equinor Petoro DNO
Total Equinor Petoro 
Total Equinor Petoro 
Total Petoro DNO 
Equinor Total Petoro
```

Comment: sorry no time for a full answer, but some hints:
1. You have a lot of redundant variables in there.. try to use one input and one output list or dictionary
2. I think this can be done in a single loop, over the combinations. You can also combine lists or dict-items. Avoid the reverse lookup (get_key) for non-unique values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension like this:

**Explanation:**

- The first `for` defines the length of the combinations. Every length from 2 to the length of `values` is used.
- The second `for` creates the actual combinations
- The `if` uses a generator method to sum the numbers of the items

```
from itertools import combinations

combis = [
    item
    for length in range(2, len(values)+1)
    for item in combinations(values, length)
    if sum(i[1] for i in item) >= 0.5
]
```

Comment: Thanks , why there is no duplicates in the combis , I was just wondering

Comment: `itertools.combinations` doesn't create duplicates on its own. They must have happend somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
import itertools  
result=[] 
for k in range(2,len(values)+1):
    temp=[tuple(x[0] for x in i) for i in list(itertools.combinations(values,k))if sum([p[1] for p in i]) >0.5]
    result.append(temp)
result=sum(result, [])
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[('DNO', 'Equinor'), ('Equinor', 'Petoro'), ('Equinor', 'Total'), ('DNO', 'Equinor', 'Petoro'), ('DNO', 'Equinor', 'Total'), ('DNO', 'Petoro', 'Total'), ('Equinor', 'Petoro', 'Total'), ('DNO', 'Equinor', 'Petoro', 'Total')]
```

Comment: but this only works for pairs of 2, the example given by the author aims to include all combinations..

Comment: Hey archer , thank you for your quick feedback , these is still some issue but I will try to figure it out .Thanks again